# How convert the last two zeroes of a number to decimal numbers

Tags: java, number-formatting, currency-formatting

```
int numb = 200000;
DecimalFormat def = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
String finalnumb =  def.format(numb);
```

The value of `finalnumb` is **200000.00** but I want it to be **2000.00**.

Please how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oney way would be dividing numb by 100.0 (double value)

```
public static void main(String[] linesInFile) {
int numb = 200000;
DecimalFormat def = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
String finalnumb = def.format(numb / 100.0);
System.out.println(finalnumb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide your number by 100.

```
int numb = 200000;
numb = numb / 100;
DecimalFormat def = new DecimalFormat("#.00);
String finalnumb =  def.format(numb);
```

Comment: Maybe the OP could clarify the question to indicate the exact type and range of input you need to be able to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Following logic may work for you.

```
    int numb = 200000;  
    double d1=numb;
    d1=d1/100;
    DecimalFormat def = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

    String finalnumb =  def.format(d1);
```